# Show admob ad in specific container Flutter

Tags: admob, flutter, flutter-layout

Hello I'm creating an app in fluter and I'm using [firebase_admob](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_admob) to show ads, I want shown ad in the card highlighted in the image but currently I only get a banner on the bottom of the screen.
is there a way to do that.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to specifically position it inside a widget (as of now). This is a known limitation mentioned in: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_admob#limitations